# Continuity of Linear Operator Between Hilbert Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, hilbert-spaces

> **Note:** Please do not give a solution; I am curious to understand why my solution is incorrect, and would prefer guidance to help me complete the question myself. Thank you.

---

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space, and suppose that $T\in\text{Hom}(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{H})$. Suppose that there exists an operator $\tilde{T}:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathcal{H}$ such that,
\begin{align}
\langle Tx,y\rangle =\langle x,\tilde{T}y\rangle,
\end{align}
$\forall x,y\in\mathcal{H}$. Show that $T$ is continuous.

**My current solution is as follows:**

Assume for all $\delta>0$ there exists $n>N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that,
\begin{align}
\|x_{n}-x\|<\delta.
\end{align}
Then,
\begin{align}
\langle Tx_{n}-Tx,Tx_{n}-Tx\rangle &= \|Tx_{n}-Tx\|^{2}\\
&\leq\|Tx_{n}-Tx\|=\|T(x_{n}-x)\|\\
&\leq\|T\|\|x_{n}-x\|\rightarrow 0\text{ as }n\rightarrow\infty.
\end{align}

What am I doing wrong? I notice I do not use the existence of $\tilde{T}$.

**Second Attempt:**

Assume $\langle x_{n},x\rangle \rightarrow \langle x,x\rangle$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Then, given $\langle Tx,y\rangle = \langle x,\tilde{T}y\rangle$,
\begin{align}
\langle Tx_{n},y\rangle &= \langle x_{n},\tilde{T}y\rangle\rightarrow_{n\rightarrow\infty}\langle x,\tilde{T}y\rangle=\langle Tx,y\rangle.
\end{align}
Therefore, $Tx_{n}\rightarrow Tx$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

**Third Attempt:**

Assume $\|x_{n}-x\|\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Then,
\begin{align}
\langle Tx_{n}-Tx,Tx_{n}-Tx\rangle=\langle x_{n}-x,x_{n}-x\rangle=\|x_{n}-x\|^{2}.
\end{align}

By assumption $\|x_{n}-x\|^{2}\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Hence,
\begin{align}
\langle Tx_{n}-Tx,Tx_{n}-Tx\rangle = \|Tx_{n}-Tx\|^{2}\rightarrow 0\text{ as }n\rightarrow\infty.
\end{align}
Therefore, $T$ is continuous.

**Fourth Attempt**

Assume $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Then, given $\langle Tx,y\rangle = \langle x,\tilde{T}y\rangle$,
\begin{align}
\langle Tx_{n},y\rangle =\langle x_{n},\tilde{T}y\rangle\rightarrow_{n\rightarrow\infty}\langle x,\tilde{T}y\rangle =\langle Tx,y\rangle.
\end{align}
Since $Tx_{n}\rightarrow Tx$ weakly, we know $Tx:=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Tx_{n}$ exists which implies that $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{H})$. Hence $\|T\|<\infty$. So,
\begin{align}
\langle Tx_{n}-Tx,Tx_{n}-Tx\rangle &= \|Tx_{n}-Tx\|^{2}\\
&\leq\|Tx_{n}-Tx\|=\|T(x_{n}-x)\|\\
&\leq\|T\|\|x_{n}-x\|\rightarrow 0\text{ as }n\rightarrow\infty.
\end{align}
Therefore $T$ is continuous.

**Fifth Attempt**

Assume $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$. Then, given $\langle Tx,y\rangle = \langle x,\tilde{T}y\rangle$,
\begin{align}
\langle Tx_{n},y\rangle =\langle x_{n},\tilde{T}y\rangle\rightarrow_{n\rightarrow\infty}\langle x,\tilde{T}y\rangle =\langle Tx,y\rangle.
\end{align}
Hence $Tx_{n}\rightarrow Tx$ weakly. Define $f_{x}(y):=\langle Tx,y\rangle$, then $f_{x}:\mathcal{H}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a linear operator.

Now,
\begin{align}
f_{x_{n}}(y)=\langle Tx_{n},y\rangle\rightarrow_{n\rightarrow\infty}\langle Tx,y\rangle=f_{x}(y).
\end{align}
Further,
\begin{align}
|f_{x_{n}}(y)|=|\langle Tx_{n},y\rangle|\leq\|Tx_{n}\|\|y\|\implies\|f_{x_{n}}\|\leq\|Tx_{n}\|.
\end{align}
Also,
\begin{align}
\|f_{x_{n}}\|\geq\frac{|f_{x_{n}}(Tx_{n})|}{\|Tx_{n}\|}=\|Tx_{n}\|.
\end{align}
Hence, $\|f_{x_{n}}\|=\|Tx_{n}\|$. We now show $\|f_{x_{n}}\|_{\infty}<\infty$,
\begin{align}
|f_{x_{n}}(Tx)|=|\langle Tx_{n},Tx\rangle|\rightarrow_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\langle Tx,Tx\rangle|=\|Tx\|^{2},
\end{align}
hence, $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|f_{x_{n}}(Tx_{n})|<\infty$ and so by the UBP $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\|f_{x_{n}}\|<\infty$. This implies $\|Tx_{n}\|<\infty$ for all $x_{n}$ and so $\|T\|<\infty$.

Hence,
\begin{align}
\langle Tx_{n}-Tx,Tx_{n}-Tx\rangle &= \|Tx_{n}-Tx\|^{2}\\
&\leq\|Tx_{n}-Tx\|=\|T(x_{n}-x)\|\\
&\leq\|T\|\|x_{n}-x\|\rightarrow 0\text{ as }n\rightarrow\infty.
\end{align}
Therefore $T$ is continuous.

Comment: The last inequality basically implies that the norm of T is bounded or that it is continuous

Comment: Comment on the second attempt: you showed that $Tx_n \to Tx$ weakly, not in norm. Off-topic comment: I admire your tenacity. Keep trying!

Comment: Thank you. Do you have a hint?

Comment: Third attempt made. Although not sure if this holds either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that we can't assume that $T$ has a finite norm. Before we add that condition about having an adjoint map $\tilde{T}$, we're simply assuming that $T$ is a linear map.

In fact, a linear map between normed vector spaces is continuous if and only if it has a finite operator norm. You assumed the statement we were trying to prove.

Second attempt: The assumption here should have been that $x_n\to x$, as in the others. Then, yes, $\langle Tx_n,y\rangle \to \langle Tx,y\rangle$ for each $y$. This is real progress. But, as stated in the comments, it's weak convergence rather than convergence in norm. Not quite there.

Third attempt: No, $\langle Tu,Tu\rangle$ is not equal to $\langle u,u\rangle$ - it's equal to $\langle u,\tilde{T}Tu\rangle$, and you don't know what $\tilde{T}T$ does. This is not helpful.

All, right, lets go back to the attempt that made some progress. Are you familiar with the [uniform boundedness principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle)? One consequence of that theorem is that any sequence of points in a Hilbert space that converges weakly is bounded. Can we use this to ensure that $T$ is a bounded operator?

Fourth attempt: No, saying that $Tx_n\to Tx$ weakly does not imply that $Tx_n\to Tx$ strongly (in norm). For example, in $\ell^2$, the standard basis vectors $e_n=(0,0,\dots,0,1,0,\dots)$ converge to zero weakly but not strongly; $\|e_n\|=1$.

Fifth attempt: This looks like it basically works. There's a key step near the end:

> ...and so once more by the UBP $\sup_{n\in N}\|T\|<\infty$

You need more than just the one sequence for that, and calling it a supremum over $n$ doesn't really make sense anymore. The argument I have is a proof by contradiction; if $T$ is an unbounded operator, we can find $y_n$ such that $\|y_n\|\to 0$ and $\|Ty_n\|\to\infty$, so then $x+y_n\to x$ and $\|T(x+y_n)\|\to\infty$.

Comment: So is the idea for me to use $\tilde{T}$ to cancel out the operator norm in my final inequality?

Comment: @Jack no, that won't rescue the proof.

Comment: New proof attempt. Please check if you can.

Comment: I am not familiar with that. I am only aware that given a family of linear operators $(T_{\alpha})$ are such that $T_{\alpha}:E\rightarrow F$, where $E,F$ are Banach spaces. If $\sup_{\alpha\in A}\|T_{\alpha}x\|<\infty$ then $\sup_{\alpha\in A}\|T_{\alpha}\|<\infty$.

Comment: Do you have a link to the corollary of Uniform Boundedness which you refer to?

Comment: It's mentioned in the [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Weakly-convergent_sequences) article. The proof? The map $f_x(y) = \langle x,y\rangle$ is a linear operator from the space to $\mathbb{R}$ with norm $\|x\|$. Apply the UBP, or the version you quoted in the other comment, to a sequence $f_{x(n)}$.

Comment: Fourth Attempt added

Comment: So what part of my fourth attempt does the proof breakdown? Surely weak convergence proves existence of a limit and hence $\|Tx_{n}\|$ is bounded?

Comment: No, weak convergence doesn't prove existence of a limit. See the example I provided.

Comment: Fifth attempt added. Feels flimsy to me, however I feel I am really close. What do you think?

Comment: I edited the last part to remove those meaningless supremums.

Comment: In fact I just realised that after conlcuding $\|T\|<\infty$ this implies $T\in\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{H})$ and so $T$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the Closed Graph Theorem?

Assume that $x_n \to x$ and $Tx_n \to y$. We claim that $y = Tx$.

For any $z \in H$ we have
$$\langle y,z\rangle \xleftarrow{n\to\infty}\langle Tx_n, z\rangle = \langle x_n,\tilde{T}y\rangle \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} \langle x,\tilde{T}y\rangle = \langle Tx,z\rangle$$

Hence $y - Tx \perp H$ and so on.